# Determining if a sum is complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $ \ f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\ , \ f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^N 2^k |z|^{2k}$

Is $ \ f \ $ complex differentiable?

Now, if I can differentiate each individual term, then I can say that $ \ f \ $ is complex differentiable?

Comment: My initial thoughts are that it isn't complex differentiable, as |z|^2 is not complex differentiable, and thus 2|z|^2 would not be either - is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No non-constant real-valued function is complex differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

More generally you can consider functions that are finite sums $f(z) = \sum a_{kl} z^k \bar z^l$. $f$ is holomorphic ( i.e. complex differentiable) if and only if $a_{kl} = 0$ for $l \ne 0$.  In other words, $f$ has to "depend only on $z$ and not on $\bar z$" .  Yours is a particular case when $k=l$ all across.